# Laravel 4 logical organisation to return wrapping text

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, word-wrap, displayobject

I wonder where can i wrap informations before displaying it in blade.

Indeed, in my view i usually use something like.

```
<td>{{ $computer->component->id }}</td>
<td>{{ $computer->component->price }}</td>
<td>{{ $computer->component->status->name }}</td>
```

Ok, it's cool but visually, it's quite poor, and I would make, for exemple, the status, "more user friendly", displaying an *icon*, with different *class*, *clor*, depending on status value.

The question is, where should I do this ? In wich file ? I can do this in the model, but its obviously not a good way to keep the MVC logical, and keep a clean code.

I try to use a presenter class, but i cant call a Component presenter in a $computer view, and I want to display this status design in other components.

If you got any ideas, suggestions, other logic, I'm "aware" !

Comment: `View` is not for processing tho, what's wrong with a `presenter` ?

Comment: If there is no `HTML` then you may create `accessor` methods in model.

Comment: There is html !

-"what's wrong with a presenter"
I can't call presenter fonction using eloquent  dynamic relations properties.
for example :
$computer->component->designStatus()
didn't works.

Presenter work only if I use $component->designStatus()

Answer (score 1):

I'll give a go at throwing another idea for you, a blade-only approach by utilizing `@include`.

*app/views/computer.blade.php*

```html
<td>{{ $computer->component->id }}</td>
<td>{{ $computer->component->price }}</td>
@include('partials.status', ['status' => $computer->component->status->code, 'label' => $computer->component->status->name])
```

*app/views/partials/status.blade.php:*

```html
<td>
    <div class="{{ $status }}">
         {{ $label }}
    </div>
</td>
```

---

Or here, making your display more flexible. I hope this isn't too messy for what you're trying to achieve.

*app/views/computer.blade.php*

```html
<td>{{ $computer->component->id }}</td>
<td>{{ $computer->component->price }}</td>
@include('partials.status', ['status' => $computer->component->status->name])
```

*app/views/partials/status.blade.php:*

```html
<td>
    @if($status == 'in stock')
        <img src="icon-in-stock.png" /> In stock
    @if($status == 'out of order')
        <img src="icon-out-of-order.png" /> Out of order
        <a href="/notify-me">Tell me when items are available!</a>
    @endif
</td>
```

Or you can mix and match the two examples above, e.g. making `<td>`'s class dependent on your status, while keeping the content inside `<td>` dependent on your `partials.status` view and so on.

Another way too could be to have another nested `@include` inside the `@if` in the above example.

Comment: Okay, i understand your way to do.
To your mind its better to do this only with blade passing array to differents view, not a bad idea ! thx